# Packed array systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

Can someone describe the following "pnum" array for me ?
Especially "mytype" size if it [3:0] or [0:3]

Thanks

```
typedef enum bit[1:0] {A,B,C,D} mytype;
mytpye [6:0] pnum;
pnum={D,D,C,C,B,B,A};
```

Comment: Your question mentions `[3:0] or [0:3]` but your code does not show it. Also the last line of your code is not legal what did you mean?

Comment: I mean the size of mytype .

Comment: Last line it is the initialization of tha array

Answer (score 0):

You declared `mytype` as an 2-bit enumeration. Each enumeration label has the same size (2-bits)so that `A` has the value 2'b00, `B` has the value 2'b01, and so on. There is no array of enumerated labels.

You declared `pnum` as a 2-dimensional packed array of 7, 2-bit enumerations. So `pnum` is an integral 14-bit type.

Your assignment is the same as if you had wrote

```
pnum = 14'b11111010010100;
```

Comment: So I understand that there is 7 group of 2 bits .why its not 2 groups of 7 bits ? Like for example : [3:0][6:0]array - it will be 4 groups 7each one .

Comment: This is explained in section 7.4.5 Multidimensional arrays in the [1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM[](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595%5DIEEE)